# Measuring PostgreSQL ODBC performance

Tags: postgresql, timing, query-performance

We are looking for an accurate (and simple) way to measure the performance, e.g. time to retrieve records from a series of SQL SELECT statements, of an existing system against a new system. We connect from a client to both systems through ODBC connections.

For example: 
1.  Record the time to retrieve all records from table A, B, and C on an existing system S1
2.  Record the time to retrieve all records from table A, B, and C on a new system S2

Assumption: 
1.  Everything is equal (from the end-user’s perspective) in S1 and S2 in term of number of records in table A, B, and C
2.  Both existing and new databases are PostgreSQL (versions may be different)

Can you provide advice or suggestion on how we can do the measurement, preferably using an open-source tool (client side)?

Thanks

Regards,
=Z

Comment: From our team discussion, there are two ways we are considering: build a Python executable and give it to team members to run; or use Alteryx to measure time to SELECT the tables. Our team is spread across the globe AU US HK SG UK. At the end, we'll take the average time. We are leaning toward Python.